# I'm having trouble fixing a mysterious toilet leak

Tags: toilet, leak

I have a Caroma (Australia) eco-style toilet. There is a recurring leak around the base but ONLY when the water supply main valve is turned on.

The toilet can have water in the bowl, and water in the tank, with no leak. There is no sweating on tanks, and no leaks from any of the visible attachment points from water main, or tank-to-bowl.

I have replaced the wax seal with no change to the leak issue.

With water valve on, it takes about 2-3 minutes before I can see water collecting round the base. When I fill the tank up, and turn off the main, the tank will drain itself, I assume into the bowl, as it does not appear round the base.

The water is clear and not stinkified so don't think it has anything to do with the outgoing pipe and seal.

Any suggestions as to where/why/how this is happening and a fix?

Comment: just a guess, but check the inlet fitting on the tank valve.  if its got a slight leak, water will drip down to the lowest point and slowly soak the ground.  It can leak in two ways, either the coupler sealing the inlet pressure or externally where it pokes in to the tank reservoir.

Comment: If the tank drains when the water is turned off, then something's wrong. Check the seal between the tank and bowl

Comment: I would put some food coloring in the tank this may show you it is leaking to the bowl then at the seal , I have seen bad seals between the tank and bowl cause this and cracks in the tank the food coloring helps to trace the leak.

Comment: Thanks responders... I've investigated most of your inputs and can find no source for leaking water on outside, anywhere. Nothing is leaking down the sides of the entire toilet at all. With no flushing involved, water just appears round the base only when the water main valve is left on for a few minutes. Puzzler.

Comment: Assume its leaking inside then, and when water supply is on, then that water leaks out the bottom of the pan. Perhaps you have a micro fissure. I would probably pull the toilet and replace it if its older.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it sounds like first your flapper in tank needs to be replaced as it’s become hard or close to being hard where it allows water to seep slowly from tank to bowl then because of this seepage it allows more cold water into tank where as it’s leaking thru bowl to discharge drain in flow the heat of room hits incoming cold water and creates what seems to be a leak when it’s causing sweating. Try changing out a 5 dollar valve see what happens. Good luck sherm from Canada.

Comment: You do realize this is a 2+ year old question and that the OP has probably fixed it by now, right?